# 2 maps one page one map is spawned from the marker of the first (2nd map not showing up)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, driving-directions

Hi Can anyone help with this? I have a map where markers note each location (duh) and then inside the marker is a get directions link which spawans a popup. Everything works fine except the map(2nd map which contains the directions) that sits above the directions in the popup doesn't show. It's just a grey box with the directions markers.

This is the js:

```
/* ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::DIRECTIONS:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: */

var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map-container');
var dirContainer = document.getElementById('dir-container');
var fromInput = document.getElementById('from-input');
var toInput = document.getElementById('to-input');

// API Objects
var dirService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var dirRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var map2 = null;

function showDirections(dirResult, dirStatus) {
    if (dirStatus != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        alert('Directions failed: ' + dirStatus);
        return;
    }

    // Show directions
    dirRenderer.setMap(map2);
    dirRenderer.setPanel(dirContainer);
    dirRenderer.setDirections(dirResult);
};

function getSelectedTravelMode() {
    value = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;
    return value;
};

function getDirections() {
    var fromStr = fromInput.value;
    var toStr = toInput.value;
    var dirRequest = {
        origin: fromStr,
        destination: toStr,
        travelMode: getSelectedTravelMode()
    };
    dirService.route(dirRequest, showDirections);
};

function init() {
    var latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.77493, -122.419415);
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, myOptions2);

    var myOptions2 = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latLng2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    // Show directions onload
    getDirections();
}




/* :::::::::::::::::::::::::::MAIN MAP::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: */



var address;
var markers;
var windows;
var mapMarkers = new Array();
var map, marker, i;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


function initialize() {
    var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0902, -95.7129);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: map_center,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    // Create a lettered icon for this point using our icon class
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    if (markers !== null && windows !== null) {

        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markers[i],
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            mapMarkers.push(marker);

            bounds.extend(markers[i]);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(windows[i]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

                    g = document.getElementById("info");
                    address = g.getAttribute("rel");
                    //console.log(address);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function () {
            $("#info").on("click", function (e) {
                toInput.value = address;
                $(".dir-overlay").css("visibility", "visible");

                // init();
                // $('#to-text').text(address); 

                e.preventDefault();
            })
        });


        $(".closeDirections").click(function () {
            $(".dir-overlay").css("visibility", "hidden");
        });

        if (markers !== null && markers.length === 1) {
            map.setCenter(markers[0]);
            map.setZoom(11);
        } else {
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This is the html (shortened):

```
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>


<div class="dir-overlay">
    <div class="overlaymap-wrapper">

        <div class="titlebar">
            <a href="#" class="closeDirections">close</a>
        </div>  
        <div class="innermap-wrapper">
        <div class="directions-inputs">
            <span class="blue-text">Starting Location</span> <input id="from-input" type="text" value="1202 edgewood ave chicago heights il" /> 
            <input id="to-input" type="hidden" value="1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA"/>
            <a href="#" onClick="init();" class="blue-button">Get Directions</a>
            </div>
            <div id="map-container"></div>
            <div id="dir-container"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The markers are being populated and pulled from the aspx code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `init()` method, `myOptions2` isn't until declared after the call to `google.maps.Map()`, which uses `myOptions2`.
Move your declaration of `myOptions2` up one line, just before the call to `google.maps.Map()`.

```
function init() {
    var latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.77493, -122.419415);
    var myOptions2 = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latLng2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map2 = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, myOptions2);

    // Show directions onload
    getDirections();
}
```